# Translitrerate paragraphs of text

Tags: localization, google-input-tools

[Google Transliterate](http://www.google.com/transliterate/) converts text to local script as I type. However I have bunch of text paragraphs which I want to transliterate in one go.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can transliterate a whole paragraph, try using Google translate instead.

**Google Translate** : [Click Here](http://translate.google.com)